# Adding an URL parameter in JS without changing page

Tags: javascript, url, browser-history

Recently I had to add an URL parameter programmatically in JavaScript. The requirements was that the parameter should change but the page should not refresh. This was done to help keep the browser state if the user would refresh the page.

I thought I would share my solution if any one else has this problem in the future.

Comment: Please provide me with feed back if there is something you do not like about the question.

Comment: The downvotes were probably because this was not a question. Could I trouble you to reword this as if you did not know the answer when it was written?

Answer (score 1):

I used the history objects [replaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History)() function to replace the urlParameter part of the location. The function is available in most new browsers.

```
/**
* Add url parameters to your current location without changing page
* @param { object } urlParams, a hash containing key value pairs
*/
function addUrlParams(urlParams){
  var oldState = history.state;
  var oldTitle= document.title;
  var oldParams= `${window.location.hash}${location.search}`; // Keep the old params      
  var newParams='';
  var paramKeys = Object.keys(urlParams);
  var paramValues = Object.values(urlParams)

  for(var i=0;i < paramKeys.length;i++){
    newParams += `&${paramKeys[i]}=${paramValues[i]}`; // Add each param from the hash
  }
  history.replaceState(oldState,oldTitle,oldParams+newParams)
}
```

Hope you find it useful.